# Optimize the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following query for find out the total no of counts.

---

```
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM contacts_lists 
  JOIN plain_contacts
    ON contacts_lists.contact_id = plain_contacts.contact_id
  JOIN contacts
    ON contacts.id = plain_contacts.contact_id
  WHERE plain_contacts.has_email
    AND NOT contacts.email_bad
    AND NOT contacts.email_unsub
    AND contacts_lists.list_id = 45897
```

---

It takes 150ms  to complete its task.
Is there any another way to run the above query?
Is there any way  to reduce the time? is it possible?  please tell me.....................................

Comment: Do you have indexes on the foreign key fields  (the various `contact_id` ones)? Do you have index on the `contacts_lists.list_id` field?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create indices (`add_index` in migrations) on your `contact_id` columns? Also it might be better to use

```
JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = contacts_lists.contact_id
# instead of: JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = plain_contacts.contact_id
```